# Update Inner Join between two tables using Inner Join/Group_Concat returns subquery error

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I was having trouble with this

```
Update Table Set 'Contains'=(Select Group_Concat(T1.FieldX) from Table T1
Inner Join Table T2
on T1.FieldA=T2.FieldA and
(T1.FieldX like concat('% ',T2.FieldX) or T1.FieldX like concat(T2.FieldX,' %'))
Group by T2.FieldX)
```

as per [Update Table with Inner Join and Group_Concat "You can't specify target table in FROM clause"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62900762/update-table-with-inner-join-and-group-concat-you-cant-specify-target-table-in)

So decided to update another table I can use the result instead. So I pulled the Select that was working and tried this:

```
Update TableY Y
Inner Join Table Y2
On Y.Y2_ID=Y2.ID
Set FieldZ=
(Select Group_Concat(T1.FieldX) from Table T1
Inner Join Table T2
on T1.FieldA=T2.FieldA and
(T1.FieldX like concat('% ',T2.FieldX) or T1.FieldX like concat(T2.FieldX,' %'))
Group by T2.FieldX)
```

and get

```
Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Assuming the error is for a similar reaso but cannot suss out what that is.

Comment: The subquery needs to be correlated so it returns only a row related to the row that's being updated.

Comment: In your first query, where do you define the alias `T1`, and why don't you use `J`? Can you show some sample data and the desired result?

Comment: @Barmar My bad I was just trying to standardize an actual query to 'typical' fields used here I shall correct.

Comment: I was trying to write an answer, but since I couldn't figure out what you're actually trying to do, I couldn't write it.

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify.